# Enable JSSE for a specific service on Weblogic server

Tags: oracle, web-services, weblogic, jsse

We are implementing a web service on WCF. The service is consumed by Oracle weblogic. Communication is done through mutual authentication over HTTPS. The only way the communication is successful is when JSSE is enabled on Weblogic server. However this makes other web services incompatible. Is there a way to enable JSSE on the web service level instead of the server level?
In other words, we need the Weblogic server to enable JSSE only for this specific web service.

Comment: Sounds like a difficult issue. https://blogs.oracle.com/vijaya/entry/enable_disable_ssl_jsse_in references that you can set it on the java command line via `-Dweblogic.ssl.JSSEEnabled=true|false` you may be able to find a way to include that for just your one app but still seems like a server wide setting. Of course the (ugly) workaround would be to make a new  managed server to host your deployment.

Comment: Incompatible how? Solve the real problem.